# Wrap variable values on different lines using vim-surround

Tags: vim

I am slowly using vim more (coming from sublime text) and am often running into roadblocks that slow me down compared to my habits in sublime.

One example is, given a block of variables and values:

```
test = Example
blob = Hello Blob World
bars = Foo Bar
```

Which I would like to change to:

```
test = "Example"
blob = "Hello Blob World"
bars = "Foo Bar"
```

In Sublime, my typical process would be to:

1. Drag a multiline cursor next to the equal sign: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Mouse
2. <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>

Which is very quick. I'm not entirely sure how to do something like this in Vim. I am using the tpope/vim-surround plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Repeat & Surroundplugin**

The repeat motion is useful here `.` (you may need the `tpope/vim-repeat` plugin).

Go to Example hit `ys$"` to wrap all text from here until the end of line into your sourrounding, press `j` to go a line down, `.` to repeat the surrounding-action and continue.
So in all it would be:

```
ys$"j.j.
```

**Visualblock (no plugin)**

Start on the `E` of `Example` and try that:

```
<c-v>jj$A"<esc>gvI"<esc>
```

Where `<c-v>` is control and v. If you watch the visual selection closly, you should be able to understand what happens, else feel free to ask.

**Visualblock and Surroundplugin**

Visual block select all the words you want to wrap (again starting on `E`):

```
<c-v>jj$S"
```

This uses visualblock to tell the surround plugin what to wrap.

Comment: @StunBrick It states clearly in the answer what the required plugins are, it is the plugin which is explicitly mentioned in the question as installed. The solution I marked with `no plugin` works with `vim -u NONE`. This Answers are all valid!

Comment: I was wrong, I made a mistake and downvoted you, could you please edit your answer so that I can undo my downvote and make it an upvote instead? The answer must be edited before SO will allow me to change votes.

Comment: @StunBrick made a small change, don't worry if it doesn't work, I can live without the points. Just make sure to read twice the next time you downvote *me* ;-) No it is alright mistakes happen.

Comment: There we go, fixed, sorry again.